# How to use Dapper Async method correctly & get data from Task<IEnumerable<T>>

Tags: c#, async-await, .net-6.0

I am trying to learn using QueryAsync method to retrieve multiple records and returning a list of objects.  When the async call returns Task<IEnumerable>, I could not figure out how to actually extract data from IEnumerable.

**TEST ENVIRONMENT**

App:  .NET 6 console app with class library:  DapperDbOps
IDE: Visual Studio 2022
Test framework: XUnit

**TEST CODE**

In class library, I created class:  DapperDbOps.DapperHelper.  It contains a method: QueryMultipleAsync (see code below). I tried to return type as "Task <List>" and got complier error.  It looks like the only way to make the code work is using "async Task<IEnumerable>"

```
public async Task <IEnumerable<T>> QueryMultipleAsync<T>(string sqlCmd)
{
    using IDbConnection db = new SqlConnection(_dbConnStr);

    var dtList = await db.QueryAsync<T>(sqlCmd).ConfigureAwait(false);

    return dtList;
}
```

Under DapperDbOps, I created a data object class:  EmployeeDO.cs

```
namespace DapperDBOps.Models
{
    public class EmployeeDO
    {
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public int Salary { get; set; }
        public string Dept { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In XUnit, setup the test project: DapperDbOpsUnitTests, and the test case DapperDbHelperTests.
To test QueryMultipleAsync, I setup the test method: QueryMultipleAsyncTest (see following code).

```
[Fact]
public void QueryMultipleAsyncTest()
{
    //Arrange
    string sqlCmd = "SELECT * FROM Emloyee";
    
    //Act
    Task <IEnumerable<EmployeeDO>> elist = dbHelper.QueryMultipleAsync<EmployeeDO>(sqlCmd);

    //Assert
    Assert.True(elist != null);

    //foreach(var e in elist)
    //{

    //}

}
```

**PROBLEM**

Eventhough the test run successfully, I was unable to access the returned data that wrapped in the Task<IEumerable>.  After the Assert statement, I tried to interate the returned elist in the foreach loop (see the statements commented out above).  It failed. I also tried to use "foreach(EmployeeDO e in elist)" and got the same error.  The error message was the following:

[image]

**QUESTIONS**

1. Am I using the correct return type with the DapperDbHelper.QueryMultipleAsync?
2. Can the QueryAsync method be used for retrieving a single record and multiple records?
3. What is the correct way of access returned data with type of Task<IEnumerable>?

I've tried to read many posts at the site and still unable to find the answer.  Any advice or assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asserting on the `Task` which your Async() call returns, convert your test to `async` and "await" the call instead:

```
[Fact]
public async Task QueryMultipleAsyncTest()
{
    //Arrange
    string sqlCmd = "SELECT * FROM Emloyee";
    
    //Act
    IEnumerable<EmployeeDO> elist = await dbHelper.QueryAsync<EmployeeDO>(sqlCmd);

    //Assert
    Assert.True(elist != null);
}
```

Comment: I made the change according to your comments.  But, I still unable to access the data in the return elist by iterating it with foreach loop.  The compiler showed the same error. I was able to use foreach loop with a  IEnumerable<T> list when it is not related to Task.  Now, the dapper call returns Task<IEnumerable<T>>.  The regular way of using a foreach loop is no longer working.  What method I should use in this case.  Please advise.

Comment: Did you add the `await` keyword?

Comment: Sorry for me not paying attention to the "await" keyword.  It is working now.  Thanks.